# Evernote OAuth for third party applications - is it possible to sign in with Google account?

Tags: oauth, evernote

Since [late 2016](https://blog.evernote.com/blog/2016/11/03/sign-in-with-google-its-faster/) it is possible to sign in to Evernote using Google account. However, it seems this feature is not accessible to third party applications - the popup dialog used during OAuth asks for e-mail address or username and doesn't have the "sign in with Google" button:

[image: Evernote OAuth window]

Is it intentional? Currently the lack of this feature makes it impossible for Evernote users using their Google account for Evernote to authenticate the third party applications. Would it be possible to make signing in with Google available during OAuth for third party applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can not be intentional, and is definitely confusing.

Right now, to sign in with Google, you need to click the "Create a new account" link and then "Sign up with Google" button. If the user has already established a link with their Google account, they will actually sign in rather than create an account.

I filed an internal ticket @ Evernote to have this fixed.